# convergence criteria of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{50}}\,{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{1+n
}{\it a}\, \left( 10000\,\cos \left( tn \right) \epsilon\,\delta_{{
1}}-10000\,\cos \left( \frac{1}{10}\,\sqrt {4201}t \right) \epsilon\,\delta_{{
1}}+4201\,\cos \left( tn \right) -4201\,\cos \left( \frac{1}{10}\,\sqrt {4201}
t \right)  \right) }{\pi \, \left( 400\,{n}^{4}-16904\,{n}^{2}+4201
 \right) }}$

I want to find out the convergence criteria of this series (if it is possible). All symbols appearing $a,\epsilon,\delta_1,t$ are parameters. I tried applying the ratio test but $\cos(tn)$ seems to be giving a problem as all I can say about it is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos(tn)$ is that it will lie in $[-1,1]$. Any ideas how I can figure out the convergence criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the numerator is bounded from above and below, but denominator contains $n^4$, which is the dominant term as $n\to+\infty$. Hence your series is comparable with
$$\sum_n \frac{1}{n^4} ...$$

Let $a_n$ denote the $n$-th term in the series. The absolute value of you numerator does not exceed 
$$a(10000\varepsilon \delta_1+10000\varepsilon \delta_2+4102 +4201)=:A,$$ 
hence 
$$\sum_n |a_n|\leq \sum_{n} \frac{A}{50\pi(400n^4-16904n^2+4201)}.$$
The convergence of $\sum_{n} \frac{A}{50\pi(400n^4-16904n^2+4201)}$ follows from limit comparison with $\sum_n \frac1{n^4}$.

Comment: Are you referring to the limit comparison test?

Comment: The limit comparison test cannot be used since you have alternate sign in the numerator. See edited answer.

Comment: I think something may have been overlooked. The denominator in $\sum_{n} \frac{A}{50\pi(400n^4-16904n^2+4201)}$ seems to be alternating signs too. In that case, the limit comparison test wouldn't hold, would it?

Comment: $\sum_{n} \frac{A}{50\pi(400n^4-16904n^2+4201)}$ is always positive for $n>6$ . So, yeah I guess it holds.